# Tween to create the effect of one object follows another-LibGdx

Tags: java, algorithm, libgdx, geometry

I have a object(named frame) on screen,it will move either left or right according to where I move my finger.

```
public  void handleSwipeInput() {
    if (MyInputProcessor.isTouchDown) {
        float movedir = MyInputProcessor.dist > 0 ? 1 : -1;
        float speed = 30;
        float actualSpeed = Math.abs(MyInputProcessor.dist) >= speed ? speed : Math.abs(MyInputProcessor.dist);
        if (movedir > 0) {
            frame.setX(frame.getX() + actualSpeed+2);
            MyInputProcessor.dist -= actualSpeed;

        } else {
            frame.setX(frame.getX() - actualSpeed-2);
            MyInputProcessor.dist += actualSpeed;
            }
    }

}

 @Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    dist+=screenX-start;
    start=screenX;
    isTouchDragged=true;
    return false;
}
```

In update() method:

```
 if (MyInputProcessor.isTouchDown && Math.abs(MyInputProcessor.dist)>5.0f)          
            handleSwipeInput();
```

This works perfect,and I am adding an array of objects(named circles) below the frame object while moving,so that,those array of elements also moves along with my finger.

So I set positions of circles[] sequentially below frame object:

```
if(parts.size()!=0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <parts.size(); i++){
            if(parts.get(i) instanceof Block){
           circles[i].setIndex(parts.get(i).getIndex()) ;

         circles[i].setPosition(frame.getX()-frame.getRadius(),
            (frame.getY()-(frame.getRadius()*3))-(60*i));
    }
```

This also works fine.Both frame and below objects gets a feel that they are moving along with my finger,and frame objects with mentioned speed.

Now I want to create an effect like,each of the circles objects should follow frame object with some delay,according to their positions.

So that it will appear like a smooth snake movement(As in snake vs block game).

For this,I tried to make use of tweens.

[image]

```
  Tween.to(circles[0], Accessor.POS_XY,0.05f)
     .target(circles[0].getX()+10,circles[0].getY())
     .ease(TweenEquations.easeInSine)
     .start(tweenManager);
     Tween.to(circles[1], Accessor.POS_XY,0.05f)
     .target(circles[1].getX()+20,circles[1].getY())
     .ease(TweenEquations.easeInSine)
     .start(tweenManager);
     Tween.to(circles[2], Accessor.POS_XY,0.05f)
     .target(circles[2].getX()+30,circles[2].getY())
     .ease(TweenEquations.easeInSine)
     .start(tweenManager);
```

But I am not able to work the logic out with tweens.

Confused of implementing a sequential delay for each circle object,according to the touch input ,with tweens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an array which contain sequential values to control the movement of circles to look like a snake.

```
  private float delayValue[]={0.03f,0.04f,0.05f,0.06f,0.07f,0.08f,0.09f,0.10f};
```

Simple tween I used:

```
 if (movedir > 0) {
                frame.setX(frame.getX() + actualSpeed);
                MyInputProcessor.dist -= actualSpeed;
                tweenManager.killAll();
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
                    Tween.to(circles[i], Accessor.POS_XY, delayValue[i])
                            .target(frame.getX() - frame.getRadius(), circles[i].getY()).start(tweenManager);
                }
            } else if (movedir < 0) {
                frame.setX(frame.getX() - actualSpeed);
                MyInputProcessor.dist += actualSpeed;
                tweenManager.killAll();
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++) {
                    Tween.to(circles[i], Accessor.POS_XY, delayValue[i])
                            .target(frame.getX() - frame.getRadius(), 
             circles[i].getY()).start(tweenManager);

            }
```

setting positions:

```
  if(parts.size()!=0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <parts.size(); i++){
        if(parts.get(i) instanceof Block){
       circles[i].setIndex(parts.get(i).getIndex()) ;

        circles[i].setPosition(circles[i].getX(), (frame.getY() - 
     (frame.getRadius() * 3)) - (60 * i));
}
```

In this way,I managed to make smooth movement as per my requirement.(Though it is not much fine as snake vs block game,but meets my requirement).